# SimpleDateFormate.parse method not parsing the selected TimeZone

Tags: java, simpledateformat

```
  private String target_time_zone = "Australia/Hobart";
  private String format    = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z";


  public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {

        Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
        TZFormat tzFormat = new TZFormat();
        System.out.println("Converted TZ Date: "+ tzFormat.TZF(date));



  }

  public Date TZF(Date dt) throws ParseException {

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone(target_time_zone);     
        SimpleDateFormat date_format_gmt = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date_format_gmt.setTimeZone(tz);
        SimpleDateFormat date_format_gmt1 = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        date_format_gmt1.setTimeZone(tz);

        System.out.println("formated value: "+ date_format_gmt.format(dt));


       return date_format_gmt1.parse(date_format_gmt.format(dt));
  }
```

OUTPUT:

```
formated value: 11/15/2012 03:16:11 EST
Converted TZ Date: Wed Nov 14 21:46:11 IST 2012
```

Actually my requirement is i want to convert the date to the target_time_zone timeZone with the format and return back the converted Date.

```
 private String target_time_zone = "Australia/Hobart";
 private String format     = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
```

here want happens is in TZF method formated date_format_gmt.format(dt) is formated the date to my given TimeZone when we parse that value it is showing previous value (actual time).

how to get the Date object with selected Time Zone.

Comment: A Date doesn't have a TimeZone. Can you rephrase your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` object always represents time in milliseconds (epoch time), it doesn't contain any timezone information. When you `format` and make it as String, then only it prints in required format with specified timezone.